# View laravel session using JavaScript

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a session cart containing array of products and I wish to get the value of each products with price and others using JavaScript

If I want to view it on my resource view blade I use my foreach loop to get each array so how can I do that and get each array in my JavaScript

Comment: Please share some code and explain what you already tried. This way you will only get downvotes.

Comment: You don't give a huge amount of information in your question, so two options would be: 1) you could create a RESTful API for use with AJAX requests; or 2) you could output and assign the cart values as JSON to a JavaScript variable.

Comment: ok i have gotten what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its really saved in a session than you can access it by:

`session()->get('keyname')`
or to check
`session()->all()`